# Create if not exists methods not available

Tags: c#, azure, .net-core, azure-cosmosdb

I have a .Net core app that I have installed the cosmos nuget package into:

```
Install-Package Microsoft.Azure.DocumentDB.Client
```

I am attempting to follow the instructions given [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/documentdb-dotnetcore-get-started) from MS that details how to create a database and the collections.

Using dependency injection, I have registered `IDocumentClient`. However, when I attempt to use this in a setup class to create the database and collections, the following methods are not listed as avaialable:

```
public void Setup(IDocumentClient client)
{
    await client.CreateDatabaseIfNotExistsAsync(new Database() { Id = databaseId });

    await client.CreateDocumentCollectionIfNotExistsAsync(UriFactory.CreateDatabaseUri(databaseId), new DocumentCollection { Id = "Identity" });
}
```

In both cases, the methods flag up as not known, and the IDE prompts me to create them. This happens even with the `Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Client` namespace defined in the file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whilst these methods exist on the `DocumentClient` class, they are not actually part of the `IDocumentClient` interface.

In this manner, you will need to pass the concrete `DocumentClient` class into the setup method, rather than the `IDocumentClient` interface.

```
public void Setup(DocumentClient client)
{
    await client.CreateDatabaseIfNotExistsAsync(new Database() { Id = databaseId });

    await client.CreateDocumentCollectionIfNotExistsAsync(UriFactory.CreateDatabaseUri(databaseId), new DocumentCollection { Id = "Identity" });
}
```

Once you do this, the methods are available as normal.

Whilst Dependency Injection/IoC generally prefers the use of Interfaces over concrete classes, it is probably ok in this instance, since the class purpose is specifically to set up and configure the database: a certain knowledge of the underlying technology here is to be expected.

Comment: "*Whilst Dependency Injection/IoC generally prefers the use of Interfaces over concrete classes, it is probably ok in this instance...*" Though it sure doesn't make testing easier. (◔_◔)